# Why Python is slow in GCP testing results

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-pubsub

I was going through one of the article from GCP and it shows Python being slowest among all.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/testing-cloud-pubsub-clients-to-maximize-streaming-performance

Is there any reason for such behaviour. Or this is common across all use cases.

Comment: Python is a scripting language that is interpreted at runtime, which tends to be slower than compiled languages. In your graph both Java and Go are compiled languages that usually are much faster than Python or Node.js. I say usually as the efficiency of the libraries can often have a major impact.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is partially explained in the article that you shared by the last part.

"There are language limitations on pursuing a shared memory threading model, so you should scale purely horizontally to more machines if that is feasible in order to reach maximum throughput while using Python or Node.js. It can be hard to get single client instances to scale beyond one core."

This performance however is only when using Pub/Sub. I suppose that the performance of the languages defers in other tasks.